# Post-Brexit Fisheries deal

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union, brexit, international-law, fishing

While progress has been made in many areas of the Brexit negotiations, Fisheries and the Level-playing-field continue to be sticking points. In particular, the EU has so far rejected a Norway-style deal on fishing because i) There are too many fish categories in UK seas to negotiate every year, and ii) Large changes in the quotas from one negotating period to the next will lead to instability and make it difficult for fishing businesses to plan over the longer term.

As a starting point, it has already been suggested that there will be a 3-year 'transition period' for fishing, where the quotas gradually and continuously decrease during this period.

In addition, instead of negotiations taking place every year, could the negotiations take place ever 2 or 3 years?

Also, could the *change* in the quotas from one negotiating term to the next be such that it does not exceed a certain amount? Note that this does not in any way constrain the total change over a longer period of time.

That way the EU Fishermen get their degree of certainty, while at the same time the Sovereignity of UK seas is respected.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question here is. The EU and UK are sovereign actors, and can agree to pretty much any reasonable condition. If they decide on 2 and 3 years period _alternating_, it still would not be any kind of legal problem. The "change in quota" is mostly a matter of wording - you need the old treaty to continue if no new treaty is agreed upon.

Comment: If you're asking whether these things can be done, the answer is probably yes.  If you're asking whether these things will be agreed, we don't know.

Comment: By 'negotiating term' I meant the one corresponding to the 'fishing quotas' alone, i.e. every 2/3 years, not the negotiations corresponding to the FTA as a whole, which are almost done.

Answer (score 3):

Norway's equivalence is **not** a valid claim.  [Norway contributes to EU funding](https://www.regjeringen.no/en/topics/european-policy/Norways-relations-with-Europe/) and accepts following a lot more rules from the EU than what it would seem the UK under Boris is contemplating.

These are probably the main reasons the EU is not willing to grant Norway-level terms to the UK.